# How to attach possible_values to a struct with structopt?

Tags: rust, clap, structopt

[`clap`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/) allows you to provide list of accepted values using [`possible_values`](https://kbknapp.github.io/clap-rs/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.possible_values) like this.

```rust
let mode_vals = ["fast", "slow"];
.possible_values(&mode_vals)
```

How to do this with [`structopt`](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.5/structopt/)?

Answer (score 8):

Since `structopt` 0.3, you can use any method from `App` and `Arg` *directly*:

```
const MODE_VALS: &[&str] = &["fast", "slow"];

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct Opt {
    /// The velocity mode
    #[structopt(short, long, possible_values(MODE_VALS))]
    mode: String,
}
```

https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#raw-attributes-are-removed-198-by-sphynx

Answer (score 1):

`clap`’s `possible_values` is exposed as a field option, as shown in [this `structopt` example](https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt/blob/ed160ae8796ea10edb15a360f1e392c4d18dbdb3/examples/enum_in_args.rs):

```
//! How to use `arg_enum!` with `StructOpt`.

use clap::arg_enum;
use structopt::StructOpt;

arg_enum! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum Baz {
        Foo,
        Bar,
        FooBar
    }
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct Opt {
    /// Important argument.
    #[structopt(possible_values = &Baz::variants(), case_insensitive = true)]
    i: Baz,
}

fn main() {
    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", opt);
}
```

Notably, this is making use of `case_insensitive` as well, to allow any case of those variants to be accepted.

If you want more granular control, you could omit `case_insensitive` and instead implement the variants yourself:

```
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Baz {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    FooBar
}

impl Baz {
    fn variants() -> [&'static str; 3] {
        ["foo", "bar", "foo-bar"]
    }
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct Opt {
    /// Important argument.
    #[structopt(possible_values = &Baz::variants())]
    i: Baz,
}

fn main() {
    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", opt);
}
```

Finally, you could also use a string array in the same manner.